# StaxEventItemWriter XML Header

Tags: spring-batch

I am using StaxEventItemWriter for writing to an XML file. I am looking out to set standalone attribute on the xml tag to true. Is there any option to set it.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `StaxEventItemWriter` and override the [`startDocument`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/xml/StaxEventItemWriter.html#startDocument-javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter-) method. Here is an example:

```
@Bean
public StaxEventItemWriter<Person> itemWriter() {
    StaxEventItemWriter<Person> itemWriter = new StaxEventItemWriter<Person>() {
        @Override
        protected void startDocument(XMLEventWriter writer) throws XMLStreamException {
            writer.add(createXmlEventFactory().createStartDocument(DEFAULT_ENCODING, DEFAULT_XML_VERSION, true));
            writer.add(xmlEventFactory.createStartElement(getRootTagNamespacePrefix(), getRootTagNamespace(), getRootTagName()));
        }
    };
    // TODO set other properties on the writer
    return itemWriter;
}
```

Comment: The `StaxEventItemWriter` already provides setters for the `version` and `encoding` attributes, so I believe it can also provide a setter for `standalone`. This will make it easier to customize the XML declaration than having to extend the writer and override `startDocument` (this way is error prone if we forget to add the root element as shown in the answer). I created a feature request here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2856. In the meantime, you can use the example in the answer.

Comment: This one sounds perfect, I switched back to jaxb meanwhile, will check this out